# Correlation Plot Font Size not coming proper while saving

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am making a correlation plot and saving it as jpg

```
corrMatrix = one_year_volume.corr()
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
sns.set(font_scale=2)
axr=sns.heatmap(corrMatrix, annot=True)
axr.tick_params(labeltop=True,rotation=0)
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
fig.savefig('One_Year_Correlation.jpg')
```

When I save the font size is not very clear and the column name strip off in jpg file , is it possible to make it more clear , as I need to present it.

Comment: To make it more clear you can increase the resolution by changing dpi, and to set the figure size you can adjust the inches `fig.set_size_inches(5, 8)`. See the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html) for more information.

Comment: `fig.savefig("file.png", bbox_inches="tight")`If so, is the font unbreakable?